# Two highchart update issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have two line chart that are identical and use same data.

I have written an update code that update both the charts:

```
c2updateLineGraph(2,[[0, 105993],[25, 659727],[50, 648727],[75, 636627],[100, 636627]]);
function c2updateLineGraph(index,data)
{
    c2chart1.series[index].setData(data, true);

        c2chart1p.series[index].setData(data, true);
}
```

My data structure is:

```
var c2graphdata=[{
                name: 'Current year',
                data: []
          },
          {
                name: 'Reapair v1',
                data: []
          },
           {
                name: 'Repair v2',
                data: []
          },
          {
                name: 'Replacement v1',
                data: []
          },
          {
                name: 'Replacement v2',
                data: []
          },
          {
                name: 'Facelift v1',
                data: []
          },
          {
                name: 'Facelift v2',
                data: []
          },
          {
                name: 'Reconstruction v1',
                data: []
          },
          {
                name: 'Reconstruction v2',
                data: []
          },

];
```

Issue is c2chart1 is getting updated, but not c2chart1p. Trick is if I swap the position of c2chart1 and c2chart1p, then c2chart1p get updated only.

I could replicate the issue here [jsfiddle.net/hhh2zx3w](http://jsfiddle.net/hhh2zx3w/) Check after 8 secs only chart1 gets updated, not chart2

Comment: Second array of object is not proper. Remove `,` from end of last object.

Comment: Could you provide us with a demo where this problem occurs. I tried to recreate it but it works without problems. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sama03gn/.

Comment: My guess it it's in the code where you are assigning the variables c2chart1 and c2chart1p.  Can we see that code?

Comment: @d_paul I could replicate the issue here http://jsfiddle.net/hhh2zx3w/
Check after 8 secs only chart1 gets updated, not chart2

Answer (score 0):

Reset the graph data and setting the data agin will work for you . just change

```
function c2updateLineGraph(index, data) {
    c2chart1.series[index].setData(data, true);
  c2chart1p.series[index].setData(c2graphdata, true); //reset the graph data
  c2chart1p.series[index].setData(data, true);
}
```

Updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hhh2zx3w/2/

Hope it helps